# How to get classy lenses with overloaded field names?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, lenses

I'm trying to build lenses for records which have the same field names. Along with that, I'm trying to "wrap/extend" these base records and want the same field names to work for the wrapped/extended records (which, I believe, classy lenses do). How do I get the following to work:

```
-- Data types for context of the code snippet below

data Download = Download {
  userId :: UserId
  ,gid :: Gid
  ,logId :: LogId
  ,parentId :: Maybe DownloadId
  ,createdAt :: UTCTime
  ,updatedAt :: UTCTime
}

data File = File {
  downloadId :: DownloadId
  ,fpath :: String
  ,len :: Int
  ,createdAt :: UTCTime
  ,updatedAt :: UTCTime
}

data Url = Url {
  downloadId :: DownloadId
  ,fileId :: FileId
  ,url :: URL
  ,createdAt :: UTCTime
  ,updatedAt :: UTCTime
}

data DownloadObject = DownloadObject {
  _key :: DownloadId
  ,_dbDownload :: Download
  ,_dbFiles :: [FileObjects]
}

data FileObject = FileObject {
  _key :: FileId
  ,_dbFile :: File,
  ,_dbUrls :: [UrlObjects]
}

data UrlObject = UrlObject {
  _key :: UrlId
  ,_dbUrl :: Url
}

fetchDownload :: DownloadId -> DownloadObject
```

Given these data types, how do I get the following lenses to work:

```
dload <- fetchDownload dloadId
dload ^. key -- of type DownloadId
dload ^. createdAt -- of type UTCTime
((dload ^. files) !! 1) ^. key -- of type FileId 
((dload ^. files) !! 1) ^. createdAt -- of type UTCTime
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `makeFields` from [`Control.Lens.TH`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.14/docs/Control-Lens-TH.html):

```
{-# language
  TemplateHaskell, MultiParamTypeClasses, FunctionalDependencies, FlexibleInstances #-}

import Control.Lens

data Bar a n = Bar {
  _barAge :: a,
  _barName :: n
} deriving Show

data Foo = Foo {
  _fooAge  :: Int,
  _fooName :: String
} deriving Show

makeFields ''Bar
makeFields ''Foo
```

Now you have the following classes:

```
class HasName s a | s -> a where
  name :: Lens' s a

class HasAge s a | s -> a where
  age :: Lens' s a
```

and the appropriate instances for `Foo` and `Bar`. Example:

```
> Foo 10 "foo" ^. age
10
> Bar 10 "bar" ^. age
10
```

You can then implement the classes for wrapper objects. Example:

```
data FooWrapper = FooWrapper {
  _fooWrapperKey :: Int,
  _fooWrapperFoo :: Foo
} deriving Show

makeFields ''FooWrapper

instance HasName FooWrapper String where
  name = foo . name

instance HasAge FooWrapper Int where
  age = foo . age
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I think you missed a crucial part of the question. I want the lenses to work on the wrapped/extended records, i.e. `DownloadObject`, `FileObject`, and `UrlObject`, NOT `Download`, `File`, and `Url`

Comment: Is there any other way to write this without having to write all the lens-related boiler-plate myself (the `HasName` `HasAge` etc instances)?

Comment: A terrible answer: You could use Template Haskell to automate much of this. The API and documentation for it are hairy, but it is doable. There is no provided way of doing this, by the lens library, as far as I know.

Comment: ah... how I miss Ruby meta-programming and Lisp macros!