# Free Monad vs explicitly passing functions

Tags: haskell

I'm exploring options in Haskell that would let me separate business logic from the technical implementation of underlying systems. For example, in the context of a web server, separate how the web server treats the information it receives from how it reads from and writes to the database. To do such thing, there are many options but two caught my attention in particular: Free Monad and passing a capability record as argument. I'm having troubles seeing what would be the pros and cons of one over the other.

A code snippet to illustrate what I'm talking about:

```hs
module Lib where

import qualified Control.Monad.Free as FreeMonad

data MyGadt x
  = Read (String -> x)
  | Write String
          x

instance Functor MyGadt where
  fmap f (Read g)      = Read (f . g)
  fmap f (Write str x) = Write str (f x)

programWithFreeMonad :: FreeMonad.Free MyGadt ()
programWithFreeMonad = do
  msg <- FreeMonad.liftF $ Read id
  FreeMonad.liftF $ Write msg ()

ioInterpreter :: FreeMonad.Free MyGadt x -> IO x
ioInterpreter (FreeMonad.Pure x)             = return x
ioInterpreter (FreeMonad.Free (Read f))      = getLine >>= (ioInterpreter . f)
ioInterpreter (FreeMonad.Free (Write str x)) = putStrLn str >> ioInterpreter x

runProgramWithFreeMonad :: IO ()
runProgramWithFreeMonad = ioInterpreter programWithFreeMonad

data Capabilities m = Capabilities
  { myRead  :: m String
  , myWrite :: String -> m ()
  }

programWithCapabilities :: Monad m => Capabilities m -> m ()
programWithCapabilities capabilities = do
  msg <- myRead capabilities
  myWrite capabilities msg

runProgramWithCapabilities :: IO ()
runProgramWithCapabilities =
  programWithCapabilities $ Capabilities {myRead = getLine, myWrite = putStrLn}
```

These two solutions are written differently so I think many have an opinion about how it looks and which one they prefer. But I was wondering if anyone had any insight about the pros and the cons of one solution over the other.

Comment: @Daniel Wagner  Whoops, sorry about that and thank you for pointing it out. I guess it was a little too late at night when I typped that code  I edited and corrected them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Even if we restrict ourselves to choosing between free monads and records-of-functions (leaving out solutions involving monad transformer stacks and MTL-like typeclasses) there's a lot of debate ongoing, and the matter it's not settled.

The simple free monad has been traditionally accused of suffering from two flaws: runtime inefficiency (which might or not be important, depending on how slow the interpreter operations are by comparison) and lack of extensibility (how to lift a program into another having a richer set of effects?).

["Data types a la carte"](http://www.cs.ru.nl/~W.Swierstra/Publications/DataTypesALaCarte.pdf) first attempted a solution to the extensibility problem. Later, the ["Freer Monads, More Extensible Effects"](http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/extensible/more.pdf) paper came out, which proposed a more sophisticated free type to increase the efficiency of the monadic bind, and also an extensible way of defining sets of operations. The main libraries implementing this approach are:

- [freer-simple](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/freer-simple) The simplest to understand of the bunch, apparently also the slowest. It seems to have some limitations on bracket-type operations.
- [fused-effects](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/fused-effects) More efficient library that allows bracket-type operations. But the types are also more complex.
- [polysemy](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/polysemy) Relatively new library which aims to be fast and support bracket-type operations while retaining simple types.

One appealing aspect of these libraries is that they let you interpret effects piecemeal, picking out one effect while leaving the rest uninterpreted. You can also interpret an abstract effect into other abstract effects, without having to go down to `IO` right away.

---

As for the record-of-functions approach. Programs like `programWithCapabilities` which are polymorphic over a base monad, and which take a record of functions parameterized by the monad, are conceptually related to what is called the [van Laarhoven Free Monad](http://r6.ca/blog/20140210T181244Z.html):

```
-- (ops m) is required to be isomorphic to (Π n. i_n -> m j_n)
newtype VLMonad ops a = VLMonad { runVLMonad :: forall m. Monad m => ops m -> m a }

instance Monad (VLMonad ops) where
  return a = VLMonad (\_ -> return a)
  m >>= f = VLMonad (\ops -> runVLMonad m ops >>= f' ops)
   where
    f' ops a = runVLMonad (f a) ops
```

From the linked post:

> Swierstra notes that by summing together functors representing
>   primitive I/O actions and taking the free monad of that sum, we can
>   produce values use multiple I/O feature sets. Values defined on a
>   subset of features can be lifted into the free monad generated by the
>   sum. The equivalent process can be performed with the van Laarhoven
>   free monad by taking the product of records of the primitive
>   operations. Values defined on a subset of features can be lifted by
>   composing the van Laarhoven free monad with suitable projection
>   functions that pick out the requisite primitive operations.

There don't seem to exist (?) libraries that give you a pre-fabricated `VLMonad` type. What does exist are libraries that take a record of functions but otherwise work over `IO`, like [`RIO`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/rio). One can still abstract over the base monad in one's logic, and later use `RIO` when running the logic. Or prefer simplicity and rip the polymorphic veil that hides the `IO` from one's logic.

The record-of-functions approach has perhaps the merit of being more easily grasped, being an incremental step-up from working directly on `IO`. It also more closely resembles the object-oriented way of doing dependency injection.

The ergonomics of working with the record itself become central. Right now it is common to use ["classy lenses"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38914782/how-to-get-classy-lenses-with-overloaded-field-names) to make the program logic independent of the concrete record type and facilitate program composition. Perhaps one day extensible records could be used as well (like extensible sum types are used in the freer approach).

Answer (score 2):

There may be some non-style considerations like performance or ease of type inference that favor one over the other (my guess is that the `Capabilites`-style approach is probably a little better for both, but benchmark before you take that as truth), but by and large they are equivalent. You can take a program expressed with `Capabilities` and run it with `ioInterprefer` [sic], and you can take a program expressed with `Free MyGatd` [sic] and run it with an arbitrary `Capabilities`.

Like this:

```
freeToCaps :: Monad m => FreeMonad.Free MyGatd () -> Capabilities m -> m ()
freeToCaps (FreeMonad.Pure x) _ = return x
freeToCaps (FreeMonad.Free (Read f)) c = myRead c >>= flip freeToCaps c . f
freeToCaps (FreeMonad.Free (Write str x)) c = myWrite c str >> freeToCaps x c

capsToFree :: Capabilities (FreeMonad.Free MyGatd)
capsToFree = Capabilities {myRead = FreeMonad.Free $ Read FreeMonad.Pure, myWrite = FreeMonad.Free . flip Write (FreeMonad.Pure ())}

runFreeToCaps :: IO ()
runFreeToCaps = freeToCaps programWithFreeMonad $ Capabilities {myRead = getLine, myWrite = putStrLn}

runCapsToFree :: IO ()
runCapsToFree = ioInterprefer $ programWithCapabilities capsToFree
```

My advice is to pick whichever feels more natural given the rest of your program, and know that if you change your mind, you can always write adapters like the above to help you refactor your program incrementally.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and sorry for the several typos  I edited my original message and fixed them .